# Storing query Results into a Variable to use later

Tags: mysql

Like the title says, i am trying to store the results of a query in a variable so that i can use it in another query that would join them. I have been trying to do this using the `INTO` santex as it describes it on google. This is what i am entering:

```
mysql> select Name, Type, Region from table1 union select Name, Type, Region from Table2 into @temp1;
```

However, with this, i am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Which does not make sense as the `Select` statement has the same number of columns. So i figure maybe its my variable, so i remove the `@` and tried it again, but i got this error:

```
ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: temp
```

So now im at a lost, what am i doing wrong? I am following the syntax that is describe on several wikis on google but with no luck.

Comment: To store multiple values you need a temp table. A variable can only store a single value. Why not join in a subquery and do it all in a single query?

Comment: it gets way to complicated as there are multiple tables being joined using all kinds of joins and unions.

Comment: How do i use temp tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary table like this.

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SalesSummary (
-> product_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
-> , total_sales DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
-> , avg_unit_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
-> , total_units_sold INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

They have great tutorials here:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your variable in your SELECT statement, and not after.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-user-variables.html